AttributeError: 'SentenceTransformer' object has no attribute 'get_config'
Attribe error
Btw I'm using kaggle notebook,I install the packages
I upgrade the sentence trandformaer on th eprev version same issues.The answerI check on github issues not working! I'm working
Libraries versions
Python 3.10.13
torch 2.1.2
sentence_transformers 2.7.0
resolved!(reinstalling the package)
